# Override configure check for specific package

Tags: package-management, configure, yocto

I'm trying to compile gstreamer-1.8 from source on Yocto linux (because latest package available for it is 1.4). Gstreamer itself compiled fine but when I'm trying to configure base plugins I get the error:

```
configure: No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
configure: error: no gstreamer-1.0 >= 1.8.0 (GStreamer) found
```

I have very limited understanding of configure scripts but judging by its source it uses pkg-config to check if required package is installed.

I have built required files from source and there is no such package for my system. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by explicitly telling pkg-config to search for gstreamer by doing

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure
```

it turned out that there were *.pc files for gstreamer that I built from source.